# What is faster to find in jQuery - ID's that start with X or a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have html and throughout you have span elements like this:

```
<span id="element-1" class="elements"></span>
<span id="element-2" class="elements"></span>
<span id="element-3" class="elements"></span>
```

What is faster to find them:

```
$('.elements')
```

or

```
$('[id^="element-"]')
```

Comment: IMO, `class` selectors as other is based on `attribute selectors`

Comment: ID, is always faster, there should be only one. Oh, I see..hmm, yeah I have to agree with Rayon, an attribute selector is crappy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think speed is a concern here, the difference between them is so quick it wont effect your code..

Comment: Didn't think of it that way, thanks :)

Comment: Until you have 1000s of elements and don't chain your jquery... then speed is a *huge* concern.   With 2 or 3... meh

Answer (score 0):

I think, id selector works faster.

HTML ID attributes are unique in every page and even older browsers can locate a single element very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Id is obviously faster then class because there can be only one Id, once found need no more search. However the speed is not concern. If you need to do some work on multiple elements you use class but if you need to do work on a particular element you use Id.

Answer (score 0):

Id's in html are auto assigned in JS.

Because there can be only 1 `id` on the page with that name. the **entire** element is assigned into a JS variable.

For example: the element `<span id='spanTagOne'>Text</span>` will be a JS variable `spanTagOne`.

So you don't even need to get them since they are already assigned.

Answer (score 0):

try this way to find

$('parent').find('.child') is a faster way to find element.